# How did the author of the book conclude this passage?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

Could someone tell me how the author completes the fifth equality from the fourth?
Consider that Lambda (gh) = Lambda (g). Lambda (h), | Lambda (g) | <= 1 for every g polynomial monic over a finite body and Lambda (1) = 1
[image]

Comment: It's a sum of a geometric series.

Comment: I'm talking about the fourth to fifth passage, when it's already a production.

Comment: Yes, and every single term is the sum of a geometric series, as shark pointed out.

Comment: This is an example of Euler product, the idea being the same as for the Riemann zeta function

Comment: my god how I had not seen this, thank you